# mysql_fetch_array() giving error, in pagination

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following Code to apply pagination in my page..

The Code is

```
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('maiarn', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use test : ' . mysql_error());
}

$sql_statement = 'SELECT * FROM Email';
$num_Array = mysql_query($sql_statement);
$total_records = mysql_num_rows($num_Array);

$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

$offset = 10;

if ($page){
    $from   = ($page * $offset) - $offset;
}else{  $from = 0;  }

$sql_statement = 'SELECT * FROM email LIMIT ' . $from . ',' . $offset;

$resultArray = mysql_query($sql_statement);

    ?>
```

And the while Loop for displaying results is:

```
      <tr>
      <?php echo  mysql_query($sql_statement); ?>
       </tr>

  <?PHP
  //row number
  $row_number = $from + 1;
  //Finally, Lets print all the rows, we've got from sql


  while($rowArray = mysql_fetch_array($resultArray) )
  {
  ?>        
  <tr>
           <td><?PHP echo $rowArray['FullName']; ?></td>
           <td><?PHP echo $rowArray['EmailAddr']; ?></td>
           <td><?PHP echo $rowArray['Message']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?PHP
   }
  ?>   
<tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="4" class="white">
    <?PHP
//Lets add the paging here
doPages($offset, 'paging_php_mysql.php', '', $total_records); 
?>    
     </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

I get error on this below line:   that" Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in"

```
     while($rowArray = mysql_fetch_array($resultArray) )
```

Also no data is being retrived from database..
Please any help

Comment: Which means `mysql_query` returned `false` because of an invalid query.

Comment: your query did not execute properly.

mysql_query returns FALSE on a select query error.

Could you echo the `$sql_statement` string and run it in phpmyadmin?

Comment: The query fails. Use `mysql_error()` to get the message. Most likely `$offset` or `$from` is not set correctly.

Comment: search and download ezSQL. It is very good for pagination!

Comment: where is your SQL query? could you post this code too? It must be somewhere in your code...

Comment: @pritaeas I have edited the question to add complete code that i m using.. I have also executed the $sqlStatement, and it gives no errors..

Comment: @HanyaIdrees: For debugging purposes, change your `mysql_query` line to `$resultArray = mysql_query($sql_statement) or die(mysql_error());`. This is for debugging and should be removed before moving your code to production.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$count=3;
$query= 'select * from  news order by id desc ' ;
$limit_str=" limit 0,$count";

if(isset($_POST['page']))
{
    $lim=$_POST['page'];
    $offset=$lim[0]*$count; 
    $lim_str=" limit $offset, $count";
    $query.=$lim_str;
}

//Form

<form method='post' >
< input type='submit' name='page[]' value='1' />
< input type='submit' name='page[]' value='2' />
< input type='submit' name='page[]' value='3' />
</form>


<?php
// Display logic
?>
```